# Getting device location from Google Play Services without requiring wifi scanning be enabled

Tags: java, android, geolocation, google-play-services

My app requires that users be within a specific location before they can use some features. To validate this, I'm using the Google Location Services API as part of Google Play Services (com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0).

This has worked for years without issue, but with Google's recent bad publicity regarding data privacy, users are asking for the app to NOT require "Google Location Accuracy" (aka wifi-scanning) be enabled.  The problem is - I don't think Play Services will allow me to check settings without it.

Sample code:

```
LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
     .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
     .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL).setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL_SUCCESS);
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder =
        new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);

SettingsClient client =  LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

task.addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
        checkLastLocation(this);
    }
});

task.addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        int statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
        switch (statusCode) {
        case CommonStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
            try {
                ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                resolvable.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sendEx) {
                mHelper.handleError(e.getMessage());
            }
            break;
        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
            mHelper.onLocationReady();
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

When this code is run, the task will always report failure if Google Location Accuracy is disabled - even if the device GPS is enabled, and no matter what accuracy level (priority) I set on the location request.  The "startResolutionForResult" will trigger a prompt to enable it.

If the user REJECTS that prompt then I can get additional information using:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    LocationSettingsStates lss = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(data);
    if (lss.isLocationPresent() && lss.isLocationUsable()) {
        checkLastLocation(this);
    }
}
```

This tells me that even though they rejected the prompt, my request for location updates will succeed but it'll be served by other providers instead.

Ideally I'd like the task to not fail, but if it has to then I'd like to be able to get the LocationSettingsStates *without* needing to bug the user with startResolutionForResult().

The API suggests that I should be able to call task.getResult().getLocationSettingsStates()) but this only works when the task has succeeded (when I don't need the info) - otherwise the call to task.getResult() generates an ApiException (the same one that was sent to onFailure).